# How to update SQL table from other table when they are on different servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-update, sql-merge

I've already run the following command to include another server instance.

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server='Server'
```

Now I'm trying to synchronize these databases using this:

```
UPDATE
    [Server].[ServerDB].[dbo].[tableName] 
SET 
    [Server].[ServerDB].[dbo].[tableName].[columnName] = [LocalDB].[dbo].[tableName].[columnName]
FROM 
    [Server].[ServerDB].[dbo].[tableName], [LocalDB].[dbo].[tableName]
WHERE 
    [Server].[ServerDB].[dbo].[tableName].id = [LocalDB].[dbo].[tableName].id
```

This gave me the following error:

> The objects "LocalDB.dbo.tableName" and "Server.ServerDB.dbo.tableName" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

So after fiddling around with it I tried various renditions of this:

```
UPDATE
    [Server].[ServerDB].[dbo].[tableName] 
SET 
    [Server].[ServerDB].[dbo].[tableName].[columnName] = [LocalDB].[dbo].[tableName].[columnName]
FROM 
    [Server].[ServerDB].[dbo].[tableName] serverDB
INNER JOIN
     [LocalDB].[dbo].[tableName] localDB
ON 
     serverDB.id = localDB.id
```

But they all give me some sort of rendition of the error:

> The multi-part identifier "Server.ServerDB.dbo.tableName.allrows" could not be bound.

Can someone spot what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have a linked server set up?

Comment: I run other commands interacting with the `[Server].[ServerDB].[dbo].[tableName]`, so I'm pretty confident it's attached. It's just this update that gives me problems.

Comment: It looks like it's trying to interpret `[allrows]` as a column name.

Comment: Sorry, that was a bad example, `[allrows]` is a column name. I meant to say `[allColumns]`.

Comment: Can you test the linked server?: `SELECT * FROM [Server].ServerDB.dbo.tableName`.  Does that return rows?

Comment: @Trinculo, yep it outputs the table.

Comment: What if you change the `FROM` to the local DB and `INNER JOIN` on the server?

Comment: @Trinculo, same error I'm afraid.

Comment: One more suggestion:  Try removing the aliases all together and typing the full name.  (remove serverDB and localDB) and then on the `INNER JOIN` use the full `[Server].ServerDB.dbo.tableName.id = [LocalDB].dbo.tableName.id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use this syntax when updating with a join:

```
UPDATE s
SET s.[columnName] = l.[columnName]
FROM 
    [Server].[ServerDB].[dbo].[tableName] s
INNER JOIN
     [LocalDB].[dbo].[tableName] l
ON 
     l.id = s.id
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'm new to SQL and that looks odd to me because it seems like you're using a variable name `s` and `l` in the `SET` before defining them in the `FROM` and `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Yes, the syntax for update with join was the issue. It is a bit wierd in SQL Server. s and l are called aliases, you have used serverDB and localDB, I used s and l - but you can use whatever alias you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE
    serverDB
SET 
    [columnName] = localdb.[columnName]
FROM 
    [Server].[ServerDB].[dbo].[tableName] serverDB
INNER JOIN
     [LocalDB].[dbo].[tableName] localDB
ON 
     serverDB.id = localDB.id
```

Comment: Yep, that looks like it did it!